# Problem Python-weka-wrapper3 with GridSearch

Tags: python-3.x, package, weka, grid-search, failed-installation

Hi i'm haveing problems with this code, i'm trying to make a gridsearch for optimize some properties

```
from weka.classifiers import GridSearch

grid = GridSearch(options=["-sample-size", "100.0", "-traversal", "ROW-WISE", "-num-slots", "1", "-S", "1"])
grid.evaluation = "CC"
grid.y = {"property": "kernel.gamma", "min": -3.0, "max": 3.0, "step": 1.0, "base": 10.0, "expression": "pow(BASE,I)"}
grid.x = {"property": "C", "min": -3.0, "max": 3.0, "step": 1.0, "base": 10.0, "expression": "pow(BASE,I)"}
cls = Classifier(
    classname="weka.classifiers.functions.SMOreg",
    options=["-K", "weka.classifiers.functions.supportVector.RBFKernel"])
grid.classifier = cls
grid.build_classifier(train)
print("Model:\n" + str(grid))
print("\nBest setup:\n" + grid.best.to_commandline())
```

I'm haveing this problems:

```
Failed to get class weka.classifiers.meta.GridSearch

Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weka.classifiers.meta.GridSearch

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weka.classifiers.meta.GridSearch
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_11771/802912337.py in <module>
      9     options=["-K", "weka.classifiers.functions.supportVector.RBFKernel"])
     10 grid.classifier = cls
---> 11 grid.build_classifier(train)
     12 print("Model:\n" + str(grid))
     13 print("\nBest setup:\n" + grid.best.to_commandline())

NameError: name 'train' is not defined
```

Any sugestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [GridSearch](https://weka.sourceforge.io/packageMetaData/gridSearch/) and [MultiSearch](https://weka.sourceforge.io/packageMetaData/multisearch/) meta-classifiers are available through Weka packages, they are not part of the core Weka distribution. In order to use them you need to install the respective packages.

If you want use pww3 for installing/managing packages, then take a look at the [examples on packages](https://fracpete.github.io/python-weka-wrapper3/examples.html#packages).

Comment: i have installed the packages with: packages.install_package("gridSearch") and still have the problem, i also checked if the installation was correct with items = packages.installed_packages()
for item in items:
    print(item.name + " " + item.url) and show all the packages correctly

Comment: Your variable `train`, ie training dataset, has not been initialized, ie a dataset loaded.